# Remove top line containing Done button from Keyboard Using Storyboard or in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Is there anyway to remove the upper bar that includes a Done button either using storyboard or in code?

I've noticed this Done button varies between IOS versions and is not present in all of them. I don't need it because I have a custom button.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed `IQKeyboardManager` in your project?

Comment: yes but I've disabled it for this view controller

Comment: How have you disabled? So that code

Answer (score 6):

try with setting an empty view as `inputAccessoryView`, this should work

```
textfield.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
```

Comment: It did not have an effect

Comment: Works for .Net Maui too

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the above code with frame zero, it works!

```
textfield.inputAccessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```